# How activate Elementor PRO locally?

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I have 1000 sites plan from Elementor PRO. I need to do some testing locally which I use localwp.com for.

How can I activate Elementor PRO locally? Clicking on Activate Elementor PRO just gives me to the login page of Elementor.com and nothing else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Activating Elementor Pro on localhost works the same as on any website. See [this guide](https://docs.elementor.com/article/326-activate-your-license-key) for more information. Note that local installs are not considered an activation regarding your licence. So you should still have 1000 sites left.

Answer (score 0):

This thread is old but I hope this helps someone.

1. you will need to create a virtual host on your local server. follow on elementor guide to for more details.
   https://elementor.com/help/staging-site-license-activation/
2. for those of you who do not know how to create a virtual host, follow the following link
   https://bootstrapcreative.com/how-to-setup-a-virtual-host-using-wamp/

Comment: Could you elaborate your answer? If the link you have provided expires, then the answer becomes low quality